# How to display Open Street Map using Ext.ux.LeafletMap in Sencha Touch2

Tags: dictionary, sencha-touch

I have been overviewing HTML5 base mobile framework and playing with Sencha Touch. It looks great but hard to be familiar with, particularly debugging. I would like to display Open Street Map and I found out a plugin called Ext.ux.LeafletMap. I put some code but I cannot get the map on the browser.

Here is my code:

app/view/Main.js

```
Ext.define("MyApp.view.Main", {
    extend: 'Ext.TabPanel',
    requires: [
        'Ext.TitleBar',
        'MyApp.view.Home',
        'MyApp.view.Map'

    ],
    config: {
        tabBarPosition: 'bottom',

        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'homecard'
            },
            {
                xtype: 'mapcard'
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

app/view/Map.js

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.Map', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    xtype: 'mapcard',

    requires: ['Ext.ux.LeafletMap'],

    config: {
        title: 'Map',
        iconCls: 'maps',
        items: [{
            layout: 'fit',
            items: [{
                docked: 'top',
                xtype: 'titlebar',
                title: 'Maps',
                items: [{
                     xtype: 'button',
                     align: 'left',
                     ui: 'back',
                     text: 'Back'
                }]
            }, {
            // Ext.ux.LeafletMap Component          
                xtype: 'leafletmap',
                id: 'leafletmap',
                useCurrentLocation: false,
                autoMapCenter: false,
                enableOwnPositionMarker: false,
                mapOptions: {
                    zoom: 15
                }
            }]
        }]
    }
});
```

Home view is shown well but nothing appears in map page. In browser debugging console has no error.
Your help would be appreciated.